# How to listen swipe left and right of whole recyclerview? not list item

Tags: android

we have listen to the recycler view's left and right swipe. Nor for a particular list item. we have searched for some other codes. its not working.

Comment: If you mentioned why you want to do this, So we can answer in that way.

Comment: What your trying to do with that swipe ? Loading some other view ? Then look for View Pager

Comment: we are loading more than 10 tabs in this module. those are all coming from api. based on that tab id. we have load data in recycler view. when we swift left we have to move left of current tab. @DhavalSolanki

Comment: And we tried ViewPager. Swiping worked fine. But when we go to 10th or 11th tab from 0th position. It didnt worked @KingofMasses

Comment: Maybe this type of library will be help you https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: not working. i have to listen left and right swipe in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

If You have to show some other views with that recycler view i.e. some other tabs (One Tab for showing recyclerview and other tabs for other different options) then you can use viewpager for this behaviour. By using ViewPager you can listen left or right swipe on whole view not on particular item.

Comment: actually we tried ViewPager. Swiping worked fine. But when we go to 10th or 11th tab from 0th position. It didnt worked